# In jQuery, can I find/produce a JSON keyname in $.post?

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, json, for-loop

I'm just getting into Ajax (well, back into it after a long absence). Right now I have a page that successfully summons a number of elements (ten for now, but it could grow or shrink), and fills each of ten divs with the corresponding text.

Right now the code uses ten lines for ten answers. What I'd like to accomplish is in the ALL_CAPS_TEXT below:

```
$.post
    (
        'getData.php',
        {
            'userId' : id,
        },

        function(data)
        {
            for(var j=0; j<10; j++)
            {
                $('#elementDiv'+j).html(data.THE_WORD_ELEMENT_FOLLOWED_BY_J);
            };
        },

        'json'
    );
```

Can it be done? Would I have to modify getData.php so it outputs an array instead of JSON?

Comment: Are you asking about the client or the server side?

Comment: Client if possible, server if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just want to interpolate the property name. That is pretty easy - just use square bracket notation:

```
$('#elementDiv'+j).html( data['element' + j] )
```

Comment: I had started a comment along the lines of "So bracket notation is an alternative to dot notation?" when I realized I should just test it for myself, at which point I was sidetracked. Anyway, this works, thanks. (I clearly have a lot more to learn about Ajax).

Comment: Correct. Square bracket notation works the same as dot notation. It's usually preferable to stick with dot notation unless you need to do interpolation like you need e.g. `['element' + j]`.